# TypeORM: Как реализовать один-ко-многим в нетипичной ситуации?

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

Я разрабатываю приложение на NestJS. В нем как и пользователи (User), так и сообщества (Public) могут создавать статьи (Article).

Вот примерный код:

```
class ArticleEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
}

class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
}
 
class Public {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
}
```

И проблема в том, что я не могу задать между ними связь. Пытался через ManyToMany в User и Public, но решение мне показалось костыльным. Есть ли более красивое и лаконичное решение? Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 0):

Ситуация вполне типичная, поэтому например так:

```
class ArticleEntity {
  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.articles, {nullable: true})
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Public, public_ => public_.articles, {nullable: true})
  public_: Public;
}

class User {
  @OneToMany(() => ArticleEntity, art => art.user)
  @JoinColumn()
  articles: ArticleEntity[];
}
 
class Public {
  @OneToMany(() => ArticleEntity, art => art.public_)
  @JoinColumn()
  articles: ArticleEntity[];
}
```

Здесь внешние колонки на статьи будут созданы в таблицах `User` и `Public`, соответственно, а в самой `ArticleEntity` соответствующие поля будут заполняться при выполнении запросов (надо указать либо, `eager = true` в опциях связи, либо `relations` при запросе, и так далее, что верно и при работе с таблицами `User` и `Public`)